# Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc ROM change

Tags: rom, sony-xperia-arc

I am interested in buying the Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc in a couple o f days, but I have a few questions.

I have heard that it runs Android 2.3, but with a Sony Ericsson shield around it.

I was wondering if there are good ROMS by professional developers that you can flash onto the device. Roms that are not bloated with all the Sony Ericson crap.

--

The smartphone I own now is a HTC HD2, I can flash good custom roms on the device. I download my roms from XDA-Developers.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure! Hopefully there are professional ROM cookers at [XDA-Developers](http://XDA-Developers.com/) that cook ROMs without any kind of bloatware. Here are some articles that I recommend you to check before flashing a new ROM:

- [Unlocking The Bootloader](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=13230061#post13230061)
- [Updating Firmware/Flashing ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=13230256#post13230256)
- [Optional: A Beginners Guide To Modding And Tweaking The Arc](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1052067)

After you done all that you are good to go flashing a clean ROM, my suggestions are:

- [[DEVELOPMENT] - CM7.0.3 - Free xperia project](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1102523)

Comment: +1 thank you. I thought xda was only for htc devices. I am going to check the links out. Although I am not sure which new device I should choose. The Xperia Arc of the Samsung Galaxy S2. I like the Arc a lot, but the software on it looks so darn cheap. SE should not have messed with the look of the OS. Maybe just added a few of there own widgets.